# Looking For a Specific Connector

Tags: connector, terminal, screw-terminal, terminal-block

I'm designing a single layer Aluminum PCB and all components needs to be SMD/SMT. I'm looking for a common connector that will deliver DC power at 24V and up to 5A minimum (10A ideally). Right now, I'm looking for terminal block style connectors that is SMD/SMT but it seems every single one is through hole.

Is there even such a thing as a SMD terminal block? If not, is there any suggestions for other types of connectors I could look into?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't want an SMD terminal block even if they existed...it would just torque right off the PCB.

Comment: What about regular 0.1" headers?  Just parallel up the pins to get to your 10A requirement.

Comment: I see. So the possibility of the terminal block being torqued off is the reason there isn't any SMT variation. I just thought of the power barrel jack. I might use the parallel method with it to get the 10A requirements.

Comment: https://www.alliedelec.com/product/weco/140-a-126-smd-12/70211950/

Comment: Interesting!! I'll take a look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

How about a part like   [691508110302](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/w-rth-elektronik/691508110302/732-5963-1-ND/5047612). Per the site, it is surface-mount and rated at 10A.

[image]

Comment: This shows a lot of promise! It's on Digikey too which makes the ordering process a lot simpler. Thanks!